# How to make multiple objects of json - using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I want to make objects in my json response i have achieved this functionality but i want to do more in my response the response currently i am getting is:

```
"privileges": {
    "facilities": [
    {
        "facility_id": 1,
        "speciality_id": 1,
        "is_facility_supervisor": 1
    },
    {
        "priv_key": "ced"
    }
    ]
}
```

But i want to add "priv_key": "ced" into my facilities object and one thing more i want to add "is_super_admin": 1. into "privileges like below:

```
"privileges": { 
    "is_super_admin": 1,
    "facilities": [
    {
        "facility_id": 1,
        "speciality_id": 1,
        "is_facility_supervisor": 1
    },
    {
        "priv_key": "ced"
    }
    ]
}
```

How i can achieve above functionalities this is is my controller code:

```php
$response = array(); 
$response['facilities'] = DB::table('users')->where('is_super_admin')->first();
$response['facilities'][0] = DB::table('user_facility')->select('user_facility.facility_id','user_facility.speciality_id','user_facility.is_facility_supervisor')->where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->first();
$response['facilities'][1] = DB::table('prev_definition')->select('prev_definition.priv_key')->where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->first();
```

and my login where i am sending response:

```php
return response()->json([
    'status' => true,
    'message' => 'Login successfully',
    'data' => [
        'privileges' => $response
    ]
]);
```

I dont have idea how to implement the above functionalities anyone there please help me your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: what' the actual output ?

Comment: Why would non-facility data go in the `facilities` array? Also, your "what I have" and "what I want" are basically identical...

Answer (score 0):

firstly get all your data that you want to map with array when you return this array using response->json([]) it will convert your array into json object.

```
$is_super_admin = DB::table('users')->where('is_super_admin')->first();
$speciality_id = DB::table('user_facility')->select('user_facility.facility_id','user_facility.speciality_id','user_facility.is_facility_supervisor')->where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->first();
$priv_key = DB::table('prev_definition')->where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->pluck('priv_key')->first();
$response = [
        'privileges'=>[
            'is_super_admin'=>$is_super_admin ,
            'facilities'=>[
             [
                'facility_id'=>1,
                'speciality_id'=>$speciality_id ,
                'is_facility_supervisor'=>1,
                 'priv_key'=>$priv_key
             ],
            ]
        ]
    ];

return response()->json([
'status' => true,
'message' => 'Login successfully',
'data' => $response
```

]);

Sample Results of $response:

```
{
    "privileges": {
    "is_super_admin": 1,
    "facilities": [
     {
        "facility_id": 1,
        "speciality_id": 1,
        "is_facility_supervisor": 1,
         "priv_key": "ced"
     },
   ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi kamran i want "prev_key": ced" into facilities object

Comment: I just edited my post so you can have better idea of whats happening all i juts did is placed array key "priv_key" in facilities array